Why does it cost so much to produce shareholder reports for an ETF?
I was looking at the Annual Report (January 31, 2024) for Vanguard's "Vanguard Real Estate Index Funds". On page 15 of that report there is a section titled "Statement of Operations". In that section, under "Expenses" I see these entries:
Shareholders' Reports—Investor Shares         1
Shareholders' Reports—ETF Shares          1,287
Shareholders' Reports—Admiral Shares        355
Shareholders' Reports—Institutional Shares  158

The numbers are in thousands. This seems to say that it cost 1.3 million dollars to produce shareholder reports for the ETF shares. How can it cost so much just to produce a report? I realize there are may be more shareholders for an ETF but this number seems excessive

These are large funds which large numbers of shareholders. By default shareholders are entitled to a paper report which they get unless they are smart enough to opt out of the paper version. This kills a lot of innocent trees and paper reports are expensive to print and to mail.

Shareholder reports require at a minimum:

People to do the work to prepare the reports
Software to generate the reports
Materials to print whatever physical copies are required.
Costs to store/distribute the reports (even electronically)

All of those have real costs. Those costs are likely allocated from the total costs to generate multiple reports across all of their funds, but it's also possible that there are some costs specific to real estate funds.
I worked for a non-financial company in the department that produces just a small part of the annual reports, and I can attest that it was a significant amount of our time for 6 people for several weeks to produce the information in the reports, and we were a relatively small part. So I can see the costs for a multi-billion dollar mutual fund to go over $1 Million quite easily
I can't speak to if the reports for an ETF are more complicated than the other share classes to explain the difference in cost, but it's more likely that the total expense for creating annual reports is allocated across all share classes similar to the report expenses themselves.
Bottom line - if you feel that this cost (0.07% of net income, 0.003% of net assets) is excessive, you are free to contact Vanguard and ask them to reduce them, or tell them you'll buy someone else's funds. If you are a significant shareholder in Vanguard they might listen to you.

Don't forge the accounting and auditing - that's very expensive. ETFs may involve much more transactions (redemptions/purchases) than mutual funds.
